# PowerShell keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

Currently I am using Bash on Windows via MSYS2. I have this file `.inputrc`:

```
"\33[1;3A": "cd ..\n"
```

Whenever I press Alt Up Arrow, it moves to the parent directory. Does PowerShell
have a similar method to map shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is excellent, but this seems to work too:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+UpArrow {
   Set-Location ..
   [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::InvokePrompt()
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/PowerShell/module/psreadline/Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PowerShell on Windows 10 uses "PSReadline" which mimics bash's Readline in many ways (though not in the terseness of ~/.inputrc). The module is also installable on older Windows.

However, I haven't actually managed to bind Alt+UpArrow successfully – no events are generated for it even if I call [System.Console]::ReadKey() – so you might have to use Ctrl instead.

You can bind keys using [Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7), either to a familiar [PSReadline action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-7) or to a custom PowerShell function:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+UpArrow -ScriptBlock {
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert("cd ..")
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```

Overall this is similar to using the 'bind' command in ~/.bashrc, and to make such bindings persistent you need to put them in PowerShell's [profile script](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/), which is located at `$Profile`:

```
PS> $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
C:\Users\Me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

PS> $Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
C:\Users\Me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind key handlers to `Alt+key`combination add this environment variable `PSREADLINE_VTINPUT=1`. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/558#issuecomment-346982057) for more details. Note that this *may cause keys using Ctrl to not work*.

**There's an edge case here that the other comments don't address** as you go up the directories you will hit the root and the command fails, so to deal with this surround the command in a try-catch block.

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key 'Alt+UpArrow' -ScriptBlock {
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()
    try { Set-Location .. }
    catch { return }
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```

> Use the try block to define a section of a script in which you want PowerShell to monitor for errors. When an error occurs within the try block, the error is first saved to the $Error automatic variable.

— [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3#long-description)

Also ensure you have the [PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7.3) module installed by running `Get-Module` in PowerShell.

### To bind more custom key/chord to handlers

- Enter `Alt+?` in PowerShell and press the key to note the string for the key/chord and it also returns the function the Chord is bound to, if any.
- Enter `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler` to find all the already available keys and their functions.
- To bind a function to a custom key add this line to your [PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3#profile-types-and-locations), replace <key> with the key you noted and replace <function> with any function returned earlier.

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key '<key>' -Function <function>
```

- You can also find more functions that are unbound with this command `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Unbound`